# Is it not necessary to draw boundary classes in the class digram

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram

Class diagram is a static representation of a system that we are going to develop.Classes can be categorized as

1. Boundary classes
2. Control classes
3. Entity classes

So when we are drawing class diagram Is it not necessary to draw boundary classes in the class diagram?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Normally when we are drawing class diagrams, we only design control classes and Entity classes. We are not going to draw boundary classes(classes which used to interface designing) . Is it not necessary to draw boundary classes in the class diagram

Comment: It alway depends on what you want to tell. The full truth is always a bit lengthy (remember that guy in the Hitchhiker's Guide?). So for clarity and brevity sake you tell only what is actually needed. If your boundaries are of no interest in a certain circumstance, you must not mention them.

Comment: thank you @ThomasKilian  +1

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to show.

**Entity-Control-Boundary (ECB)** is a variation of the Model View Controller Pattern.

If your application does not follow the **EBC** pattern there is no need to mark classes as Entity, Boundary or Control.

You may also use Class Diagramms to show the relationship between some of the classes, like how the Mediator Pattern may be implemented.

From Wikipeda: Mediator Pattern UML Diagram

[image: Wikipedia: Mediator Pattern UML Diagram]

There is no Entity, Control or Boundary.

So in the answer is - in general there is no need to draw Entities, Boundaries or Control elements in UML Class Diagrams, only if your classes implement something like the ECB Pattern.

Comment: My question was " Is it not necessary to draw boundary classes in the class diagram?" I know that it is not necessary to name it as ECB in the class diagram. Normally we include only control and entity classes to the class diagram.we are not going to include boundary classes. So Is it not necessary to draw boundary classes in the class diagram?

Comment: And the answer is "it depends". If you want only to show the relationship between Entites and Control then no, if you want to show the relationship between Control and the Boundaries then of course yes and if you want to show the complete picture then also yes.

Comment: When we were asked to draw it at the  question paper for a  particular scenario , what is the best option?

Comment: That soul like you have a UseCase you'll have to describe.  Then you'll usually have some thing like a sequence digram for the scenario. If the sequence diagram shows the boundary you'll have to add it also to the class diagram. At least all classes that occur in the sequence diagram should occur in the corresponding class diagram. If you just want to show only how the use case is implemented than you don't need the boundary. I don't know enough about your context and the people that will read the diagram to give a better answer.

Comment: ECB is one of approaches to modelling. If you follow ECB methodology you should include boundary classes where those apply (still you might have a diagram representing some part of a system that doesn't contain any). If you're not following ECB no such concept exists and then you don't use boundary classes. Note that ECB is not part of UML however it has some standardized methods to depict those classes (and thus can be treated as extension to UML) .
How should you answer on a test is a separate thing. Answer as you were taught at the specific course.We're not able to guess that.